# Convert SpriteKit Particle Emitter to plist

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit, particle-system

I want to use SpriteKit's particle Emitter to generate particles for my Cocos2D video game. The particle is exported into an .sks file, and I need it to be in a .plist file format for this to work on my Cocos2D game any ideas?

Comment: They are two incompatible formats so my "idea" would be to a) try and write a converter (it won't produce the exact same results though since SK and CC particle systems work differently, interpret parameters differently, and are probably not even feature-compatible) or b) use a particle editor that's compatible with Cocos2D. I recommend b).

Comment: Any recommendations for particle editors?

Comment: Particle Designer is the most popular one. Download it from https://71squared.com/particledesigner. It is a paid one,trail version allow you to experiment with it without exporting your project. There is an online flash based particle designer. Check it out at http://onebyonedesign.com/flash/particleeditor/

Answer (score 0):

technically it already is a plist file. sks is actually just a binary plist file.

you can convert it back to an xml plist using plutil. eg. plutil -convert xml1 some.sks

it needs to be conveyed back into binary format before you can use Xcode to edit the sks again though.

I doubt highly that the resulting plist file would be even the slightest bit like the plist cocos2d would be looking for though. I have no cocos experience so I don't know what it needs.